# Using Jquery-Ui-Map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using jquery-ui-map plugin to use certain features of Google Maps.

And I'm using this feature ...

Link: http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-google-maps-geocoding.html

Code:

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap().bind('init', function(event, map) { 
$(map).click( function(event) {
    $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', {
        'position': event.latLng, 
        'draggable': true, 
        'bounds': false
    }, function(map, marker) {
        $('#dialog').append('<form id="dialog'+marker.__gm_id+'" method="get" action="/" style="display:none;"><p><label for="country">Country</label><input id="country'+marker.__gm_id+'" class="txt" name="country" value=""/></p><p><label for="state">State</label><input id="state'+marker.__gm_id+'" class="txt" name="state" value=""/></p><p><label for="address">Address</label><input id="address'+marker.__gm_id+'" class="txt" name="address" value=""/></p><p><label for="comment">Comment</label><textarea id="comment" class="txt" name="comment" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea></p></form>');
        findLocation(marker.getPosition(), marker);
    }).dragend( function(event) {
        findLocation(event.latLng, this);
    }).click( function() {
        openDialog(this);
    })
});
```

My question is simple, how can I add a limit markers on the map? example just one?

Thanks a lot...

:)

Comment: See sample in the link you provided (https://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/wiki/jquery_ui_map_v_3_sample_code): there is an `addMarker` method `$('#map_canvas').gmap({'callback':function() { this.addMarker( { /*id:'m_1',*/ 'position': '42.345573,-71.098326', 'bounds': true });}});`

Comment: Correct, however I would like to put a limit...
Using this example the user can for several markers on the map and I would like to allow only one.

Comment: What are you calling a limit marker?

Comment: Yes... i want to allow the user to place a marker on the map only.

Comment: I still do not understand, where can be your marker if it is not in the map??